# How to use AWS CodeArtifact *within* A Dockerfile in AWSCodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codeartifact

I am trying to do a pip install from codeartifact from within a dockerbuild in aws codebuild.

This article does not quite solve my problem: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/using-python-packages-in-codebuild.html

The login to AWS CodeArtifct is in the prebuild; outside of the Docker context.

But my `pip install` is *inside* my Dockerfile (we pull from a private pypi registry).

How do I do this, without doing something horrible like setting an env variable to the password derived from reading `~/.config/pip.conf/` after running the login command in prebuild?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the environment
variable: `PIP_INDEX_URL`<sup>[[1]](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/#environment-variables)</sup>.

Below is an AWS CodeBuild `buildspec.yml` file where we construct the
`PIP_INDEX_URL` for CodeArtifact by using
[this example from the AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/python-configure-pip.html#python-configure-without-pip).

> ##### **`buildspec.yml`**
>
> ```yaml
>   pre_build:
>     commands:
>       - echo Getting CodeArtifact authorization...
>       - export CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN=$(aws codeartifact get-authorization-token --domain "${CODEARTIFACT_DOMAIN}" --domain-owner "${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}" --query authorizationToken --output text)
>       - export PIP_INDEX_URL="https://aws:${CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN}@${CODEARTIFACT_DOMAIN}-${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.d.codeartifact.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com/pypi/${CODEARTIFACT_REPO}/simple/"
> ```

In your **Dockerfile**, add an `ARG PIP_INDEX_URL` line just above
your `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` so it can become an environment
variable during the build process:

> ##### **`Dockerfile`**
>
> ```
> # this needs to be added before your pip install line!
> ARG PIP_INDEX_URL
>
> RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
> ```

Finally, we build the image with the `PIP_INDEX_URL` build-arg.

> ##### **`buildspec.yml`**
>
> ```yaml
>   build:
>     commands:
>       - echo Building the Docker image...
>       - docker build -t "${IMAGE_REPO_NAME}" --build-arg PIP_INDEX_URL .
> ```

As an aside, adding `ARG PIP_INDEX_URL` to your Dockerfile shouldn't break any
existing CI or workflows. If `--build-arg PIP_INDEX_URL` is omitted when
building an image, pip will still use the default PyPI index.

Specifying `--build-arg PIP_INDEX_URL=${PIP_INDEX_URL}` is valid, but
unnecessary. Specifying the argument name with no value will make Docker take
its value from the environment variable of the same
name<sup>[[2]](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg)</sup>.

**Security note:** If someone runs `docker history ${IMAGE_REPO_NAME}`, they can
see the value
of `${PIP_INDEX_URL}`<sup>[[3]](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg)</sup>
. The token is only good for a maximum of 12 hours though, and you can shorten
it to as little as 15 minutes with the `--duration-seconds` parameter
of `aws codeartifact get-authorization-token`<sup>[[4]](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/codeartifact/get-authorization-token.html)</sup>,
so maybe that's acceptable. If your Dockerfile is a multi-stage build, then it
shouldn't be an issue if you're not using `ARG PIP_INDEX_URL` in your target
stage. `docker build --secret` does not seem to be supported in CodeBuild at this time.

Comment: thanks for this! I will investigate switching to this methodology

Comment: Will docker cache the stages after ARG PIP_INDEX_URL after the token refreshes ? If not is there a workaround ?

Comment: @Roy If the value of `PIP_INDEX_URL` changes, I'm pretty sure the cache is invalidated starting at the line that the `PIP_INDEX_URL` is first referenced. To get around this, you could create some kind of builder image in a _separate_ `Dockerfile` and push that image to an image repository. Then refer to _that_ in your final image's `Dockerfile` using `FROM myrepo/mybuilder as builder` **or** `COPY --from=myrepo/mybuilder /thing.py /app/thing.py`. You would then manually recreate your builder image _only_ when your `requirements.txt` changes instead of every time your `PIP_INDEX_URL` changed.

Answer (score 5):

So, here is how I solved this for now. Seems kinda hacky, but it works. (EDIT: we have since switched to @phistrom answer)

1. In the prebuild, I run the command and copy `~/.config/pip/pip.conf` to the current build directory:

```
pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      ...
      - echo Fetching pip.conf for PYPI
      - aws codeartifact --region us-east-1 login --tool pip --repository ....
      - cp ~/.config/pip/pip.conf .
  build:
    commands:
      - docker build -t $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG .
      - docker tag $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
```

2. Then in the Dockerfile, I `COPY` that file in, do the `pip install`, then `rm it`

```
COPY requirements.txt pkg/
COPY --chown=myuser:myuser pip.conf /home/myuser/.config/pip/pip.conf
RUN pip install -r ./pkg/requirements.txt
RUN pip install ./pkg
RUN rm /home/myuser/.config/pip/pip.conf
```

Comment: Using this method your pip.conf (and the credentials it contains) will still be contained in the docker image because of the way the layered file system in docker images works, which is not best practice.

Comment: @Snorfalorpagus that is true; however it is only good for 12 hours (the file will be invalid then). But i agree, and we have switched to using the other answer here (which came after this)