# AWS Codeartifact and docker build cache

Tags: docker, pip, docker-build, aws-codeartifact

Im trying to use AWS Codeartifact as my pip repo.
every time I build a docker image I need to login or generate token,
I tried this: [How to use AWS CodeArtifact *within* A Dockerfile in AWSCodeBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67426509/how-to-use-aws-codeartifact-within-a-dockerfile-in-awscodebuild)

but in each build the pip.conf file is different (new token) which breaks the docker cache.

for now I want to avoid base image with all the packages pre-installed.

anyone has a solution for this problem?

thx!

Answer (score 3):

looks like docker buildkit is the answer.

Makefile:

```
docker_build:
    @$(eval CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN := $(shell aws codeartifact get-authorization-token --domain your-domain --domain-owner your-id --region your-region --query authorizationToken --output text --duration-seconds 900))
    @pip config set global.index-url "https://aws:${CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN}@<your-domain>-<your-id>.d.codeartifact.<your-region>.amazonaws.com/pypi/your-repo/simple/"
    cp ~/.config/pip/pip.conf /tmp/pip.conf
    DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --progress=plain --secret id=pip.conf,src=/tmp/pip.conf -t tmp_docker_image .
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.8-slim-buster
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=pip.conf,dst=/root/.pip/pip.conf \
pip install -r ./requirements.txt
```

I have tested it couple of times, changed the token on each run, looks good.

this one helped: https://dev.to/hugoprudente/managing-secrets-during-docker-build-3682